# ID token rejected by Google Sign-in

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm having trouble logging in to my Node.js REST API with Google Sign-in. The login works fine when I'm using my Vue.js frontend with Axios. But it doesn't work when I'm using Postman, and this prevents me from testing it.

I've created my project in Firebase, enabled Authentication. I intend to use only email/password authentication. Firebase Console created the Firebase SDK Snippet:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIza...AA",
  authDomain: "myproject-bcd3e.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myproject-bcd3e",
  storageBucket: "myproject-bcd3e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "13337141888",
  appId: "1:13337141888:web:ace61d519026919f63c89d"
};
```

A service account has also been generated on Google Cloud Platform. It has a `Client ID` and a `Client Secret` key.

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "667614098088-d3rbps7vc2f0p8b3rkvc86evpgcv98oa.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "myproject-bcd3e",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "SUY-...-...FJ",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "https://myproject-bcd3e.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler", "http://localhost:3001", "https://localhost:3001", "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback"
        ],
        "javascript_origins": ["http://localhost", "http://localhost:5000", "https://myproject-bcd3e.firebaseapp.com", "http://localhost:3001", "https://localhost:3001"]
    }
}
```

In Postman I created a new OAuth2 Authorization Token with the following configuration:

```
Token Name:                                   Google
Callback URL:                                 https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:                                     https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
Access Token URL:                             https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Client ID:                                    *client_id from the service account JSON*
Client Secret:                                *client_secret from the service account JSON*
Scope:                                        openid
State:                                        *random string*
Client Authentication:                        Send client credentials in body
```

When I click the `Get New Access Token` button in Postman, it opens the browser and loads the Google authentication screen. **Problem:** It's not a password login, and I don't see an option for that.

The sign-in process then finishes successfully and Postman collects a valid-looking ID token.

But when I pass this token to my backend, and it verifies it with `auth().verifyIdToken()`, the result is this error:

`Unable to sign in: Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "myproject-bcd3e" but got "667614098088-d3rbps7vc2f0p8b3rkvc86evpgcv98oa.apps.googleusercontent.com". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.`

Apparently there's something about confusing the `Client ID` with the `Project ID`. What's wrong?

Comment: 1) You are mixing two different authentication systems (Firebase and Google). To implement your email/password testing, you cannot use Google, use Firebase. 2) To prevent confusion, you did not create a service account, you created an OAuth Client secrets configuration. Very different from a service account. 3) The token is failing as you generated the token with the wrong auth system.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Good thing it's so straightforward...